# E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed Error (kotlin- android)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android

In kotlin I am making app to signUp, Login and then after successfull signIn user will be forwarded to home screen 
where all users will be displayed, So I am fetching data from database to show in the recyclerView and getting this error :(
 please help.

```
2022-03-24 10:38:46.835 9086-6305/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11817, ga_screen_class(_sc)=SignUp, ga_screen_id(_si)=5165931126923283161}]
2022-03-24 10:38:46.925 2079-3402/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.chatplusapp/com.example.chatplusapp.SignUp/1
2022-03-24 10:38:46.925 2079-3402/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.chatplusapp/com.example.chatplusapp.SignUp/1
2022-03-24 10:38:56.753 9086-6305/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=9550, ga_screen_class(_sc)=SignUp, ga_screen_id(_si)=5165931126923283161}]
2022-03-24 10:38:56.772 9086-6305/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=SignUp, ga_previous_id(_pi)=5165931126923283161, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=5165931126923283162}]
```

**Here is my main activity code where fetch and display user data details into recyclerView adapter code is there.**

```
package com.example.chatplusapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<User>
    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        mDbRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()



        userList= ArrayList()
        adapter= UserAdapter(this, userList)




        userRecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
        userRecyclerView.adapter= adapter



        //read the value from the database
        mDbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                
                userList.clear()

                //snapshot is use to get how schema of the database is
                for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    //create user object and add it to the user list
                    val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                    //if current user is there then dont display that to the list
                    if(mAuth.currentUser?.uid!=currentUser?.uid){
                        userList.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                }
                
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId==R.id.logout){
            //write the code for sign-out
            mAuth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, LogIn::class.java))
            finish()
            return true
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage())`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?